# My android app loads successfully but shuts downs immedaitely

Tags: android, c++, ant, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK to port my C++ game over to mobile. I've debugged all the code successfully using ndk-build. And I've all successfully run ant-debug. I then installed the app onto my android device and the compiler said it was a success. However when I press the icon on my android screen, the app loads a black surface onto the screen and then shuts down after about 1 second. Could anybody suggest what might be the problem here? Has anybody experienced anything similar? I would like to know which area to start looking for the bug.

Comment: post your code and your log

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Without more info it's very unlikely we're going to be able to provide any sensible advice short of just randomly guessing ...

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing here, but It could be due to to permissions. Those are usally located in the manifest file of the android application. If the application requires certain prviliges, but those are not not granted the app would start and crash immediately.